# git pull from remote master branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

1. I forked a repo on GitLab
2. Cloned my fork to my local machine
3. Made some changes, then pushed to my fork.
4. Some changes have been made on the *original repo* and I want to `git pull` so everything is up to date.

#### Is this possible?

I've tried `git pull` and `git pull origin master` and got everything is up-to-date. (makes sense)

`git pull upstream` gave me the following message:

> You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify
>   a branch.

I don't know how to specify these branches, everything thing i've tried returns branch does not exist. But I feel this is the right direction..

#### Branches:

```
 * master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/master
```

I'm not sure the difference between these two branches. Or which one is the original repo to begin. I'm all out of `git pull` ideas and feel there might be something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

1. Checkout in your forked repo in the branch you wish to pull into (preferably master).

```
git checkout master
```

2. Pull the repo in your repo's branch using absolute path

```
git pull https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git BRANCH_NAME
```

3. Handle merge conflicts if any.
4. Commit the merge and push to master

```
git commit -m "pulled parent repo"
git push origin master
```

**Method 2**
1. Go the root directory of project. 
2. Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to master will be stored in a local branch, upstream/master.

```
git fetch upstream
```

3. Check out your fork's local master branch.

```
git checkout master
```

4.Merge the changes from upstream/master into your local master branch. This brings your fork's master branch into sync with the upstream repository, without losing your local changes.

```
git merge upstream master
```